# Showing Color for all 4 option Problem, rather green color for right answer and red color for givenanswer and if both same then show green Color

Tags: flutter, dart

Showing Color for all 4 option Problem, But I Want to show green color for correct answer and red color for given answer and if both same then show green Color. But by this code showing Red color for all 4 option if this is wrong and show green color for all 4 option if it is right. Now give me a solution to show show green color for correct answer and red color for wrong answer. and if the answer and given answer is equal then show green color only. other option as it is.

````
class CustomRadioButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String label;
  final String optionData;
  final bool isCorrectAnswer;
  final bool isGivenAnswer;

  CustomRadioButton({
    required this.label,
    required this.optionData,
    required this.isCorrectAnswer,
    required this.isGivenAnswer,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Color labelColor = Colors.black;
    Color optionColor = Colors.black;

    if (isGivenAnswer && isCorrectAnswer) {
      labelColor = Colors.green; 
      optionColor = Colors.green; 
    } else if (isGivenAnswer && !isCorrectAnswer) {
      labelColor = Colors.red;
      optionColor = Colors.black;
    }

    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 7, 0),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 24.0,
            height: 24.0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
              color: Colors.transparent,
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.purple, width: 1),
            ),
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                label,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: labelColor, // Set label color based on conditions
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 15.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 8),
          Expanded(
            child: TexText(
              optionData,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: optionColor, // Set option color based on conditions
                fontSize: 14.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}











class MCQExamanswer extends StatefulWidget {
  final int mcqeid;

  MCQExamanswer({required this.mcqeid});

  @override
  _MCQExamanswerState createState() => _MCQExamanswerState();
}

class _MCQExamanswerState extends State<MCQExamanswer> {
  Future<List<MCQExamAnswerModel>>? _questions;
  List<MCQExamAnswerModel> questions = []; // List to store questions
  late Timer _timer = Timer(Duration.zero, () {});
  late StreamController<String> _timerStreamController;
  //static const int _timerDuration = 60; // 1 hour in seconds
  late int _timerDuration;  // Declare _timerDuration here
  bool loadingQuestions = false;
  double _totalMarks = 0;
  Map<int, String> selectedOptions = {}; // Initialize the map

  Future<void> fetchData(User user) async {
    loadingQuestions = true;
    setState(() {});
    try {
      final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('https://happy.com/questionbankappsapi/fetchmcqexamrightanswer.php?weid=${widget.mcqeid}&sid=${user.sid}'));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final List<dynamic> jsonData = json.decode(response.body);
        final List<MCQExamAnswerModel> fetchedQuestions = jsonData
            .map((json) => MCQExamAnswerModel.fromJson(json))
            .toList();
        setState(() {
          questions = fetchedQuestions;
          _questions = Future.value(fetchedQuestions);
        });
      } else {
        throw Exception('Failed to load questions. Status Code: ${response.statusCode}');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // Handle error, e.g., show error message to the user
      print('Error: $e');
      // You can show an error message to the user here using a Snackbar or AlertDialog
    } finally {
      loadingQuestions = false;
      setState(() {});
    }
  }



  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    User user = Provider.of<User>(context, listen: false);
    fetchData(user);
  }


  Widget buildQuestionWidget(MCQExamAnswerModel question, int questionNumber) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              /* Text(
                'প্রশ্ন- ${widget.questionNumber}. ',
                style: GoogleFonts.notoSansBengali(
                    fontSize: 17, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),*/
              Flexible(
                child: TexText(
                  'প্রশ্ন-${questionNumber}ঃ '+
                      '${question.questionwithequ}',
                  style: Theme.of(context)
                      .textTheme
                      .titleMedium
                      ?.copyWith(color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  mathStyle: MathStyle.text,
                ),
              ),

            ],
          ),
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              CustomRadioButton(
                label: 'ক',
                optionData: question.option1,
                isCorrectAnswer: question.givenanswer == question.answer,
                isGivenAnswer: question.givenanswer.isNotEmpty,
              ),
              CustomRadioButton(
                label: 'খ',
                optionData: question.option2,
                isCorrectAnswer: question.givenanswer == question.answer,
                isGivenAnswer: question.givenanswer.isNotEmpty,
              ),
              CustomRadioButton(
                label: 'গ',
                optionData: question.option3,
                isCorrectAnswer: question.givenanswer == question.answer,
                isGivenAnswer: question.givenanswer.isNotEmpty,
              ),
              CustomRadioButton(
                label: 'ঘ',
                optionData: question.option4,
                isCorrectAnswer: question.givenanswer == question.answer,
                isGivenAnswer: question.givenanswer.isNotEmpty,
              ),





            ],
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 10),
        Divider(thickness: 1, color: Colors.grey),
      ],
    );
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title:  Text('সময়ঃ মিনিট বাকি আছে'),

      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          children: [
            // Watermark logo
            Opacity(
              opacity: 0.1, // Set the opacity level of the logo
              child: Image.asset(
                'assests/logo.png', // Path to your watermark logo image
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
            // Question widgets

            FutureBuilder<List<MCQExamAnswerModel>>(
              future: _questions,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  List<MCQExamAnswerModel> questions = snapshot.data!;
                  return SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      itemCount: questions.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        final question = questions[index];
                        final questionWidget = buildQuestionWidget(question, index + 1);
                        return questionWidget;
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                } else {
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                }
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}```

Now give me a solution to show show green color for correct answer and red color for wrong answer. and if the answer== givenanswer then show green color only.other option as it is.
````

Comment: `isCorrectAnswer: question.givenanswer == question.answer,` is the same for all four subwidgets.  Did you have something to vary those with?

Comment: you need to also check for `label==question.answer` lack of which is marking all options as right or wrong.
Basically, check if the label value at position `i` is equal to `answer` of question.